# Updating Record in a table VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update the record in an Access table using the below code and get an error that the data type is mismatch in criteria expression :

```
If Not (Me.frmdamagesub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmdamagesub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
  With Me.frmdamagesub.Form.Recordset
    Me.txtquantity = .Fields("Quantity")
    Me.txtquantity.Tag = .Fields("Quantity")
    Me.cmdedit.Caption = " Update"
    CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE damaged_card " & _
    " SET Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity & "'" & _
    " WHERE Quantity=" & Me.txtquantity.Tag

  End With
End If
```

Comment: I am sorry but i forget to mention the error that i have faced !

Comment: Which row produces the error?

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE damaged_card " & _
        " SET Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity & "'" & _
        " WHERE Quantity=" & Me.txtquantity.Tag

Comment: My guess it you need to play with the '-s (quotation marks). You shouldn't use quotation marks around numbers. `txtquantity` and `txtquantity.tag` - are they numbers or texts?

Comment: it is numbers but data type in a table is text

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing to texts, try it like this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE damaged_card " & _
" SET Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity & "'" & _
" WHERE Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity.Tag & "'"
```

Notice the added `'`-s.

### Debugging

If it still fails, check the values in runtime and try running the SQL manually and see if it works that way. To extract the statement in runtime, have VBA output it into the Immediate window (ctrl+g) like this:

```
 debug.print " UPDATE damaged_card " & _
" SET Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity & "'" & _
" WHERE Quantity='" & Me.txtquantity.Tag & "'"
```

Do this before you try to execute it.

Then you can go to Access, create a new query, change the view to SQL view, and paste the produced SQL statement. Before executing it with Run, it is worth taking a look at the affected rows by clicking the View button and selecting Datasheet View.

[image: Query View button]

This displays all the rows from the target table that will be affected by the change. If no rows are displayed, that means no row fits your criteria, and nothing will be changed.

---

To be honest, your query doesn't make much sense, as it says: "update the Quantity to 5 where the Quantity is 5". You might want to rethink you where clause.

Refine your query in Access, and once it works, paste it back to the VBA code.

Comment: The error was disappeared but the field was not updated !

Comment: I have run SQL manually and see that the value entered in the quantity field (quantity is 1000 ) is not updated successfully (UPDATE damaged_card  SET Quantity='5' WHERE Quantity='5')

Comment: Are you sure about the where clause? Try checking which rows it would select by changing to datasheet view (next to the run query button) - I assume this is Access...

Comment: I don't understand your solution can you please give me more details as i am beginner on this

Comment: OK, see my update. You might want to rethink your Query, at the moment, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem!